# JwtBearer TokenValidationParameters don't seem to be Tested

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4, bearer-token

This question relates to JwtBearer token configuration on a .Net Core API project.

Recently a colleague of mine updated Identity Server 4 to v4 and as a result, there were some breaking changes to the way tokens were supplied, most importantly the removal of the `aud` (audience) element in the token (ref: [IDS4 docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html?highlight=AddAuthorization#validating-scopes)).

I was advised to configure the following in an ASP.Net Core API Startup.cs, and I added additional checks of the token header (ValidTypes check) and Key, which had been tested by the previous use of an '`.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options => ...)`' configuration.

```
services.AddAuthentication(
        options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }
    )
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer",
        options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://<<my_identity_server.com>>";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                
                ValidTypes = new[] { "at+jwt" },
                
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<<key/secret>>")),
            };
        });
```

Without these TokenValidationParameters settings, especially the '`ValidateAudience = false`', I get errors related to an empty audience ("The audience 'empty' is invalid"), so I have some confidence that these settings are being read and applied to some extent.  However, if I change the *correct* expected header type ("at+jwt") or my key/secret value to an *incorrect value*, no errors result, and the API continues to returns results calls in to it.  I have also attempted to add many TokenValidationParameter setting such as ValidateIssuer and ValidIssuer also without triggering errors on mismatch.

What am I missing that might be preventing these items from being tested properly?

Comment: ASP.NET Core is notorious for having issues with services overriding each other's configuration in all sorts of ways when they call those extension methods on the service collection and application builder. It sounds like you are most likely having such a problem, but it's hard to know what exactly, without seeing your startup configuration. Btw, one known "issue" is that adding Identity (i.e. AddIdentity() and AddDefaultIdentity()) sets up authorization, so you have to place your own AddAuthentication() call after these.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Leaky; development priorities mean I won't be able to look at this for a day or two but I am grateful for your comments and will come back to this soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found out a fairly conclusive answer to the tests of the 'ValidTypes' value which triggered this question.  The answer was found in the [updated IDS4 docs](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/apis/aspnetcore/jwt/),  where there is a comment:

> "On .NET Core 3.1 you need to manually reference the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt Nuget package version 5.6 to be able to check the type header."

Sure enough, this is a .Net Core 3.1 project, and after installing the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt package (currently at v6.8.0) I can get tests to auth to fail when I put a 'bad' expected value in the TokenValidationParameters, and then the local logs show errors such as:

`info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[7] Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10257: Token type validation failed. Type: 'at+jwt'. Did not match: validationParameters.TokenTypes: '*****NOT_MY_JWT_HEADER_TYP*****'.`

Correcting the expected ValidTypes to `ValidTypes = new[] { "at+jwt" }` now works.

I'm really baffled how one is meant to discover things like this with middleware; it wasn't that I did not have the right version of the package... I did not have the package installed at all! I find it confusing.

I also mentioned in the question that I had tried to force failures by setting a *bad* expectation for a symmetric key value... but my api calls were not failing.  I am less certain about this, but it turns out my colleague had decided to change the hashing of the JWT to use an asymmetric key. Thus, I would speculate that some part of the middleware was ignoring the *symmetric* key I was setting, as it identified that a different type of algorithm was in use on the token?